# Javascript Fetch value cannot be used

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch-api

I am trying to fetch a string from an API, I `console.log` before return, it is the word I need and it is a string, but my 'const wordineed = async1()' is not a string, what did I miss?

```
const async1 = async ()=>{
    try {
        const response = await fetch(url, options);
        const result = await response.text();
        console.log(result.toUpperCase());
        console.log(typeof(result.toUpperCase()))
        return result.toUpperCase()
       
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
    }

const wordineed = async1()
```

I am expecting to get a string that can be used from the function `async1()`.

Comment: All async functions implicitly return a Promise. You will have to `await` it at the call site: `const wordineed = await async1();` which means that can only happen in an async function. See e.g. https://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321

Comment: An `async` function returns: 1) A promise if called synchronously (because if you don't wait for it to complete, there is no known return value yet), 2) It's actual return value as was passed to `return` if called asynchronously with `await`. See my in-depth explanation with a table [here](https://github.com/standard/standard/issues/1442#issuecomment-592679689).